# How to discover which dpi phone is using?

Tags: android, delphi, dpi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using `TMapView` and I've seen that depending on the phone type the Marker icon gets bigger or smaller on the screen, I assume that this may have something with the dpi (xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi) that the phone uses.

How to discover which of them to select a proper icon?

Comment: check your screen dimensions that in which category it is lying

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXDeviceMetricsService.GetDisplayMetrics

Comment: Finding out device bucket is easy, however, different devices can be in same density bucket and have different physical density. And you will always have somewhat different sizes on different phones. Your question lacks details, and it is not clear whether this is the problem, or something else. Please add more details and [mcve]